# How do i use this library along with its sample?

Tags: android, android-studio, github, android-library

https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport

I cloned it but confused what to do next as i do not see any sample and run button is also disabled.Steps written are confusing and incomplete.

Comment: In addition to the other two answers, keep in mind that the author specifies some caveats: "It uses Reflection in a couple of method calls to access some hidden APIs, so it might break on some Android version, or in the future...This library will NOT do anything that is not strictly needed for this to build/work. Since this class has since been removed from AOSP, this library should be considered DEPRECATED." Even following the correct procedures it may not work out-of-the-box for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport/releases/tag/v2.1.1) is the sample app of this library. you can view its code too here.
If you are using Android studio then add this library in '**build.gradle**' file, like this

```
dependencies {
// Your other dependencies...
compile 'net.frakbot:glowpadbackport:2.1.1'
  }
```

Comment: Please make it an answer. if your problem is solved

Comment: Error:(25, 0) Cause: assert localProps['keystore.props.file']
       |         |
       |         null
       [ndk.dir:/home/android/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/ndk-bundle, sdk.dir:/home/android/Downloads/android-sdk-linux]
<a href="openFile:/home/android/Desktop/android/GlowPadBackport-2.1.1/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: but i am getting this error in log cat

Comment: I think your previous integration is still causing this problem. Make sure you have integrated through dependency in build.gradle only

Answer (score 1):

The documentations are clearly written. First compile the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.frakbot:glowpadbackport:2.1.1'
}
```

And add this in your view (`XML`)

```
 <net.frakbot.glowpadbackport.GlowPadView
        android:id="@+id/incomingCallWidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        app:targetDrawables="@array/incoming_call_widget_2way_targets"
        app:handleDrawable="@drawable/ic_in_call_touch_handle"
        app:innerRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_inner_radius"
        app:outerRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_target_placement_radius"
        app:outerRingDrawable="@drawable/ic_lockscreen_outerring"
        app:snapMargin="@dimen/glowpadview_snap_margin"
        app:vibrationDuration="20"
        app:feedbackCount="1"
        app:glowRadius="@dimen/glowpadview_glow_radius"
        app:pointDrawable="@drawable/ic_lockscreen_glowdot"/>
```

And when the `Glowpad` is triggered there are several methods you can `override` But focus on `onTrigger` method. Do what ever you want using the parameter `target` and reset the `Glowpad`.

```
glowPad.setOnTriggerListener(new GlowPadView.OnTriggerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGrabbed(View v, int handle) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onReleased(View v, int handle) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onTrigger(View v, int target) {
                Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "Target triggered! ID=" + target, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                glowPad.reset(true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onGrabbedStateChange(View v, int handle) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinishFinalAnimation() {
                // Do nothing
            }
        });
    }
```

[Source code partially copied](https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport)